# Relation between

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Can anybody please give a relationship among these objects.
Varieties, schemes, moduli spaces, stacks, algebraic spaces, groupoids.
I mean here, we can define an abstract Variety as a scheme with certain properties and so on, and a stack as a algebraic space.
I just wanna see how these related in general in a way similar to for examples
Vector spaces, modules, groups...etc.

Comment: DM Stacks $\cong$ groupoids  > algebraic spaces > schemes > varieties.

Comment: Stacks > Algbraic Stacks > Artin Stacks > DM Stacks. One thinks of schemes and everything above them as functors defined from schemes to sets or (2-categories). A moduli space is typically such a fuunctor. It can be a scheme, it can be a algebraic space and it can be a stack. Historically questions of moduli provided the motivation to look at these generalizations.